# How can I reliably detect a View has moved on the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'd like to keep track of the visual position of a View, avoiding as many callbacks as possible. Ideally, I want to do something like this:

```
View.addOnViewMovedListener(new OnViewMovedListener(){

  @Override
  public void onViewMoved(View v) {
    myCode.noticeViewMoved(v);
  }

});
```

I can't just extend View, as this needs to work for any view at all.

The best approach I have so far is adding an OnPreDrawListener to the ViewTreeObserver. That's the only way I can get a callback on changes made with View.setX() and View.setY(), but this happens if there's an invalidation anywhere in the view hierarchy, which is very suboptimal.

What other options are there?

Comment: Views don't move in a way that would allow them to have such a listener. Why do you even need it?

Comment: If a View is invalidated and visible, that should be enough to get what I want, and that information certainly exists.

I'm trying to maintain view bounds for all views in a hierarchy without polling the X/Y coordinates, for complicated reasons which I won't go into.